# Is CodeIgniter's ActiveRecord resource intensive?

Tags: php, activerecord, codeigniter

I’m coding an application with server resources in mind, so I don’t want to use too much so that this application scales in the future. I don’t mind writing my own queries. So, is ActiveRecord resource intensive for my application? Or does it not make a difference?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[CI's ActiveRecord](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html) is basically not an [ActiveRecord](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html), but a Query Builder. It allows you to form simple queries in an object oriented manner. Like with any abstraction, assembling from object state into a SQL query is slower than hardcoding it, but I suspect the performance impact to be negligible.

Answer (score 2):

- For the basics website(blog) I think
  CI active records are fine. I think
  it is always important to have a good
  database schema(normalize tables).
- I believe you could view [debug](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/profiling.html)
  information. You should look at the
  SQL query the module creates and look
  at the time spent executing query. It is always important to profile your queries. Don't just make assumptions.
- I think it is more important to have
  [opcode](http://devbee.com/opcode_cache_for_dummies)-cache and cache your
  sql-queries in memory in for example
  apc/memcached/redis if possible.