# how to separate data access layer in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, data-access-layer

I used to write the data access functionalities in model itself. Now I want to separate data access from business logic. I am using codeigniter as framework.
It seems that one way of doing it is use ORM, but it will have a performance penalty I guess.

are there any general best practices?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at [POEAA](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/index.html)'s Data Source Architectural Patterns:

- [Table Data Gateway](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/tableDataGateway.html)
- [Row Data Gateway](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/rowDataGateway.html)
- [Active Record](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html)
- [Data Mapper](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html)

CodeIgniter claims to use ActiveRecord, [but it doesnt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480929/is-codeigniters-activerecord-resource-intensive/2480944#2480944). It's more like a rudimentary [QueryObject](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/queryObject.html). To truly separate your DAO from your Domain objects, you have to use a DataMapper. Depending on the complexity of your mapping needs you can build one yourself or use an [ORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108699/good-php-orm-library). Ironicaly, the majority of ORMs in the PHP World are based on ActiveRecord, [which is pretty ill-suited for ORM](http://kore-nordmann.de/blog/why_active_record_sucks.html). Doctrine 2 is the only I know that uses a DataMapper approach.

An ORM will always come with a performance penalty (and it can be a serious one). However, you should not rule out an ORM just because of that. Handcrafting an efficient DataMapper in a high [impedance mismatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_impedance_mismatch) scenario can be tedious and difficult work. Again, see POEAA for a list of common Object-Relational patterns.

There seems to a [DataMapper implementation for CodeIgniter with Overzealous DMZ](http://www.overzealous.com/dmz/). I have never worked with it and cannot say anything about it. It just came up after a quick google, so I thought I add it here.